# Accessibility VoiceOver does not work on a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accessibility

I have a situation where the Accessibility VoiceOver just does not work.

I have a customView having a `UIImage` (imageSample) and a `UILabel` (labelSample)

This same `CustomView` is used at two different screens within the app.

Screen 1 — This works!
View -> `MainScrollView` -> `MainStackView` -> `OptionAStackView` -> `CustomView`

Screen 2 — This does NOT work!
View -> `MainScrollView` -> `MainStackView` -> `ContainerView` -> `StackView` -> `StackView` -> `OptionBStackView` -> `CustomView`

The voiceOver for the label works on Screen 1 but fails on Screen 2. Does anyone have ideas on why VoiceOver would fail on Screen 2? Does the layout having multiple stack views affect VoiceOver? Does voiceover has issues handling multiple stack views.

Note: Accessibility is enabled for the UI label. And disabled for the view above this label in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility is finicky when working with objects that are heavily layered. If multiple subviews of your `MainScrollView` have `.isAccessibilityElement` set to `true`, then it is possible that a view located below your `customView` is the one that is being selected. To check if this is the case, you can tap your second screen to place the focus on the screen and then swipe right to continue moving the focus through the view hierarchy. If you manage to eventually reach the `contentView` on your second screen, then you know that the focus is initially landing on a different layer than you wanted.

My guess is that the `ContainerView` is the initial landing location of the focus. If you set `ContainerView.isAccessibilityElement = false`, this might be able to solve your problem.